# short of/ shot something

Tags: meaning

> I was planning to bake cookies, but I was short a cup of flour.
>
> I was planning to bake cookies, but I was short **of** a cup of flour.

Does 1 mean that I had some cups of flour but I was missing one which would allow me to bake?

Does 2 mean that I was missing a cup of flour and didn't have any flour apart from that cup which I needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either construction could mean either of the two proposed meanings. Without more words it is ambiguous. The second construction may not be popular in many regions but may be understood by many many English speakers.

Comment: As a British English speaker, I would find _short of_ much more idiomatic.

Comment: Interesting - as a US English speaker, I find "short a X", with no *of*, to be more idiomatic.